# No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject when returning JSONObject

Tags: json, spring-boot, org.json

I am migrating my project from springMVC to springboot. One of the controller has an API returning in this way.

I am trying to return JSONObject,

Here is my interface:

```
public class myController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = { RequestMethod.GET, 
 RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody JSONObject myfunction(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

I get the the following error:

> No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject

I have added jackson dependencies. I want to return JSONObject only. I have seen solutions but they are advising me to convert to a string. But i cannot do that as this could affect when i am returning to the front end(Which has been written already in jsp and jQuery and is expecting a JSONObject.)

How do i solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of **JSONObject** return response as a **Java bean**, So at front end you receive it as JSON String and parse this JSON String using JSON.parse() method of JavaScript to get JSONObject.

Comment: Alright but I would like to avoid changes in the front end code base.

Comment: But Jackson cannot convert the JSONObject to JSON String. you may use ResponseEntity.

Comment: I have used ResponseEntity, it is returning to front end but the data was not getting parsed even though i sent JSONObject as the data type for ResponseEntity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectNode of Jackson library to keep JSONObject structure refer [link](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html). For that you have to autowire **ObjectMapper** in your service

```
public class myController{

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;

  @GetMapping
  public ObjectNode sayJSONObject() {
   ObjectNode objectNode = jacksonObjectMapper.createObjectNode();
   objectNode.put("key", "value");
   return objectNode;
   }
}
```

Comment: i am returning JSONObject from service/DAO layer as well. And also, objectnode's key value pair doesnt work for custom data types. we have to first convert to jsonNode and then add it as a key value pair.